# Access forbidden for identity on javascript Twilio chat SDK

Tags: twilio

I'm using twilio chat javascript SDK and I'm having problems when I try to create a new channel and invite a user.
Both users (sender and receiver) receive this error:
Error: Access forbidden for identity

But if I go to the dashboard, the channel is created with the 2 members.
What am I doing wrong?

PS: I'm creating user tokens as listed on Twilio API, I don't believe token could be a problem because the message is already sent.
It seems the problem happen when I join the channel.

My code to create the channel:

```
this.client.createChannel({
  uniqueName: roomName,
  friendlyName: 'My Channel',
  type: 'private'
}).then(channel => {
  this.channel = channel
  this.channel.join()
});
```

My invite code is just:

```
this.channel.invite(user)
```

and to generate  user tokens:

```
new Fingerprint2().get(fingerprint => {
  this.fingerprint = fingerprint

  let AUTH_TOKEN = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content')

  fetch('/chat/tokens', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      fingerprint: fingerprint,
      authenticity_token: AUTH_TOKEN,
      email: email
    }),
    headers: {
      'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
      'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
  }).then(result => result.json()).then(data => {
    callback({ token: data.token, username: data.username })
  })
})
```

and on my API

```
user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])

account_sid = ENV['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID']
api_key = 'SKe9fcdbefe0bdc1f01af4aa50d3548b70'
api_secret = 'oslALMC18tCZrUhBRDPin5KbqPSR9Rr4'

service_sid = ENV['TWILIO_SERVICE_ID']
device_id = params[:fingerprint]
identity = user.username
endpoint_id = "FakeEndPoint:#{identity}:#{device_id}"

grant = Twilio::JWT::AccessToken::IpMessagingGrant.new
grant.service_sid = service_sid
grant.endpoint_id = endpoint_id

token = Twilio::JWT::AccessToken.new(
  account_sid,
  api_key,
  api_secret,
  [grant],
  identity: identity
)

render status: 200, json: { token: token.to_jwt, username: user.username }
```

a token sample:

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImN0eSI6InR3aWxpby1mcGE7dj0xIn0.eyJqdGkiOiJTS2U5ZmNkYmVmZTBiZGMxZjAxYWY0YWE1MGQzNTQ4YjcwLTE1MDExNjA0MjAiLCJncmFudHMiOnsiaWRlbnRpdHkiOiJqb25hdGFzIiwiaXBfbWVzc2FnaW5nIjp7InNlcnZpY2Vfc2lkIjoiSVMwYThiM2NkYTllMTU0YTUyOTg3MjJkOTRjOTI5ZjBhOSIsImVuZHBvaW50X2lkIjoiSGlwRmxvd1NsYWNrRG9ja1JDOmpvbmF0YXM6ZmU2NGZjYTA5NDc4YjYzNjNlYTFiMzA3OGQzOTQwM2MifX0sImlzcyI6IlNLZTlmY2RiZWZlMGJkYzFmMDFhZjRhYTUwZDM1NDhiNzAiLCJuYmYiOjE1MDExNjA0MjAsImV4cCI6MTUwMTE2NDAyMCwic3ViIjoiQUMxN2VmODM5N2JhODJkZWQ2ZDlmZmE0ODFkMWI2YTczMSJ9.UF8XtcEBN8LSCKVvBRscu9CmYdgMVobTd84RowF5KaU
```

Comment: Can you share the code you are using to generate the channel and invite the users? Also, it might be helpful if you can share an example access token too.

Comment: I just updated my answer @philnash.

Comment: Can you include how you are inviting the users too? Also an example access token?

Comment: Edited again @philnash

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible that it's a race condition between creating the channel and joining it? When do you get the error?

Comment: I create the channel and wait for twilio response, when twilio reponds with the channel then I just join it. I thought it was when I try to get the last messages, but even without getting the last messages, the error appears, after all process (create, invite, join).

Comment: So, when you call `channel.join()` you haven't joined the channel until the [`Client#channelJoined`](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/chat/releases/1.0.4/docs/Client.html#event:channelJoined) event has fired. That's what I mean by the potential race condition. Can you make sure you're updated to the latest Chat SDK (1.0.4) and only try to do things with the channel once the event has fired.

Comment: You saved my day. I have to wait `channelJoined` event to start handle with my channel. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Awesome! Glad it's working. I'll just write that up as an answer so that others don't have to trawl through the comments here. If you could mark it as correct when it's done, that'd be sweet. Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you join a channel (with `channel.join()`) the promise resolves when the request to join the channel succeeds. This doesn't mean that the channel has been completely joined yet.

Instead, you should listen for the [`channelJoined` event on the chat client](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/chat/releases/1.0.4/docs/Client.html#event:channelJoined). Once that fires you can be certain you are now a member of that channel and can interact with it.

So, if you join a channel, you should listen for the event like this:

```
this.client.on('channelJoined', function(channel) {
  console.log('Joined channel ' + channel.friendlyName) 
})

this.client.createChannel({
  uniqueName: roomName,
  friendlyName: 'My Channel',
  type: 'private'
}).then(channel => {
  this.channel = channel
  this.channel.join()
});
```